# Does [bricked] need to be bricked?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[bricked](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bricked) has been used with 16 questions, but it is applicable to a pretty high percentage of questions.  It's good information about the current condition of the equipment, but it's too meta to be useful as a tag and should just be included in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, since it's currently applied to many different things (routers, BIOS, SSDs, even Windows), nobody can be an expert in all things [bricked](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bricked). It's kind of like saying something's broken - not helpful in the least.

I might be on board with, say, a [bios-bricked](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bios-bricked) tag because it's entirely possible for somebody to be an expert in saving toasted BIOSes.

Comment: It was probably intended to identify the "starting point" for any solution (totally dead is a unique diagnostic condition that can apply to anything and determines the next step in most cases).  It's purpose was context, like the platform on which the problem occurred or the environment in which a solution must work.  However, it does nothing to steer answerers or aid in searches, so it has no value as a tag.